# Pylons TextMate Bundle

Tags: sqlalchemy, pylons, mako

I am looking for a TextMate Bundle for Pylons development. Does anyone know of an existing bundle for Mako and/or SQLAlchemy.

I found these two existing articles but the links are no longer valid

If someone knows of a currently active link please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hey Ryan. Had the same issue, but eventually found it cached somewhere. Anyhow, for future generations I've put up a new Git repo with it:

http://github.com/williamsjj/Mako.tmbundle

Just put the Mako.tmbundle here: ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles/